# How to set up smtp server on windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, smtp

I am need to make a web form on one of my company websites and have it email it and save the information to an excel spread sheet. I have made a form but I am working on sending the email now and I have found this [script](http://www.brainjar.com/asp/formmail/default2.asp). There was a smtp server already installed on the server before I got here so i made an entry for the website but I don't think i know how to configure the script to access the server. When i run my form i get an error saying "Email send failed: The transport failed to connect to the server". For the smtpserver in the script I put my internal ip address. Is the server name that would go there or do i just have the smtp server set up wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure smtp is working properly on the server, start telnet from the Command Prompt (cmd.exe) and follow [Microsoft's example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323350) to test connecting to local smtp server and sending to your email address.

There's a LOT to setup if you want to send email from your server to an internet email address, including proper DNS A, MX, PTR, etc.  Even if you were able to send the email, without the proper DNS config you email would just be caught as spam.  That question has been answered here many times btw.